# Sort ArrayList of objects based on (dynamically changing) key

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I'm trying to sort an ArrayList of object according to a dynamically changing key.

```
 public class My Objects {
 public String name;
 public int id;
 }

 String[] nameKeys = {"key1", "key2", "key3"};
 ArrayList<MyObjects> ObjectArray = new ArrayList<MyObjetcs>();
```

Now I want to sort ObjectArray using anyone of the keys found in the "keys" variable.
The user will determine which key will be used.

I've been stuck on this for several hours so I'd appreciate any help I can get.
Thanks

Edit:

```
ObjectArray.add( new MyObjects("key1", 1);
ObjectArray.add( new MyObjects("randomname", 2);
ObjectArray.add( new MyObjects("anothername", 3);
ObjectArray.add( new MyObjects("key1", 4);

sort("randomname", ObjectArray); //What I'd like to be able to do
for( MyObjects ob : ObjectArray)
area.append(ob.name+"->"+ob.id+"\n");



Result:
randoname->2
key1->1
key1->4
anothername->3
```

Second edit:
I was going about this problem all wrong from the start. Thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: Does the example mean that you want provided key be the first, others - lexicographically sorted?

Comment: Consider what happens when you add an extra element to your `ObjectArray`: `ObjectArray.add(new MyObjects("xkey", 5);`. Should that be sorted after `"randomname"` or before it?

Comment: @AlexeyMalev not exactly. Rather it sort based on the first letter, an d if two words begin with the same letter it looks at the second letter and so on.

Comment: @user3574052 Sorry, I do not understand. "r" goes before "k" as the first letter..

Comment: For all it's worth, I've discovered a hole in my original thoughts around this. You are absolutely right and now I realize why this post was so confusing. Thank you for your answers, it's back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `Comparator` for that.

Let's imagine user selected `keys[0]` as the key sorting needs to be based on.

First, create a `Comparator` either as a separate class or as an anonymous. It should have a `compare()` method (for the way I went I need a separate one):

```
public class KeyBasedComparator implements Comparator<MyObjects> {
    public final String key;

    public KeyBasedComparator(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public int compare(MyObjects object1, MyObjects object2) {
        if ("key1".equals(this.key)) {
            return new Integer(object1.id).compareTo(object2.id);
        } else if ("key2".equals(this.key)) {
            return object1.name.compareTo(object2.name);
        }
        //some other key-based logic possibly here
    }
}
```

Ok, now we have this comparator. We're going to sort it like this:

```
Collections.sort(ObjectArray, new KeyBasedComparator(keys[0]));
```

Comment: So let's see if I understand this: The if-statement you wrote out compares the "key" string only, and to compare others keys I'd have to add an else if for every new key. Correct?

Comment: Well, for my guess - yes. You created `MyObjects` class with `int` and `String` field - it is not clear how to create external key-based sorting criteria so I wrote first came to my mind, maybe stupid one. Maybe if you explain how exactly the key affects way you want to sort objects, I'll come up with a better `Comparator`.

Comment: The keys are placed in a JComboBox. When the user choose one of the keys the object will be printed out in a textarea in the order they were sorted. So if "key3" is choosen by the user all objects will be sorted by that id (key3) and then presented. The keys are not unique btw, there could be several objects with the same key.

Comment: Can you please explain what does it mean "will be sorted by that id (key3)"? I mean, you don't have `key3` field in your class.

Comment: Well "key3" is a value for String name in this example.

    ObjectArray.add( new MyObjects("key1", 1);
    ObjectArray.add( new MyObjects("anotherkey", 2);
    ObjectArray.add( new MyObjects("anotherkey", 4);

Now I want to sort ObjectArray based on what key the user provides. Do realise now using "key1..3" was not the best for my original example. Sorry for the confusion that might have caused. I want them to be sorted alphabeticaly. So in this example if choose "key1" as key to sort by then "anotherkey" would be the last object, since it begins with "a".

Comment: @user3574052, still not a very good explanation from my point of view. Why don't you update your question with real objects and real data that you add to the ArrayList. Given that you object has two properties you would generally sort on the "name" property or the "id" property. I don't understand what the "key" is referring to.

Comment: @user3574052 Updated my example with key1 -> sort by id, key2 -> sort by name. The idea behind should be clear.

Comment: Updated the original post. Hope it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a couple of different ways.

The first is to write a `myObjectSort` function that takes the key you'd like to sort by, and uses it to perform the sort by passing the appropriate `Comparable` object to the sort.

The second is to capture this in an object that takes the key at construction (and perhaps via a setter) and performs the sort via the same `Comparable` object.

I can provide code if you give a bit more information on what the keys actually do and how you intend to sort with them.

Comment: Basically: The keys will tell what object in the ArrayList I want to use.

    New MyObject("key1",1);
    New MyObject("key2",2);
    New MyObject("key3",3);

If I (the user) choose "key" then the arraylist will be sorted by that string and presented in this new sorted order. Make sense?

Comment: No because that doesn't provide an actual ordering. If the user asks for the list to be sorted by "key1" and you have the objects you listed in the ArrayList, what should the resulting list look like?

Comment: The ordering would start with "key1" descend in natural order. If it was "key3" it would be the same. As I said in another comment there could be several objects with the same key.

Comment: Right, i'm asking you to specify what that natural order is. If the user picks "key3" what's the natural order for your ArrayList? (It's very much not clear to me that there's a good answer to this question).

Comment: Alphabetically. So if the key is a high letter (z,x) low letters would be sorted last (a,b,c)

Comment: What if the user picks 'm'? Do you sort high or low? And when they pick 'x', what do you do with 'y' and 'z'? Do they show up before 'x'?

Answer (score 0):

You can create different Comparator implementations and if you are on Java 8, you can use Stream API to run it in parallel or sequential.

Sample code will be:

```
Stream<String> names2 = Stream.of("aBc", "d", "ef", "123456");
    List<String> reverseSorted = names2.sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(reverseSorted); // [ef, d, aBc, 123456]
```

Note that `Comparator.reverseOrder()` is one of the comparator provided by java.